# What does it mean "to leave predictors out of each batch of indicators?"

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity

I've currently started reading the book "Data Analysis using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models" by Gelman and Hill. On page 5, there is a line saying "In addition, it would be necessary to leave predictors out of each batch of indicators to avoid collinearity."

The sentence was from where the authors give an example of the estimation of state-level opinions from national polls. The model included 85 categorical predictors.

First of all, I don't get what the "batch of indicators" means, and how does it help to avoid collinearity.

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is

> In classical regression, it would be unwise to fit this many predictors [85] because the estimates will be unreliable, especially for small states. In addition, it would be necessary to leave predictors out of each batch of indicators (the 4 age categories, the 4 education categories, the 16 age × education interactions, the 51 states, and the 5 regions) to avoid collinearity.

The collinearity point is that if you have an indicator for each of the four age categories, then (since everybody has an age category), you could add the same amount to each age category coefficient and subtract that amount from the constant in the regression and get exactly the same fit, with no way of choosing between the options. The same issue arises with the other categories of indicators, which removes the option of simply excluding the constant in the regression.

One solution is to choose a base age category (e.g. the 18-29 year olds), a base education category (e.g. "less than high school"), a base state etc. and not have an indicator for those particular bases.  The coefficients of the remaining indicators then suggest the impact of changing from one category to another (e.g. the difference between 30-44 and 18-29 year olds, rather than actually being 30-44).